# C# cant find anchor property in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I can't find the anchor option in VS2015, it is supposed to be under *layout*.

Where is it?

Comment: It is under layout by default, however, you can always sort alphabetically to be sure. What control does not have the property available in the objet explorer, or is it all controls?

Comment: For what type of Control are you trying to find anchor? For example if you try to find it for the Form you won't be able because form has not it.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Winforms app and not WPF?  WPF controls do not have an `Anchor` property. They use `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` instead.

Comment: Oh you are right D Stanley, My bad, it is wpf. I thought they were the same  .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the control's Properties window (select the control, hit F4, search for Anchor property).

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/